# Run octave-cli in vscode terminal

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, octave, gnu

I am a Windows user, I want to use octave in the terminal of vscode. 
I have put octave to the environment variable, but when I type `octave` in the terminal, it pop out the gui version.
I have tried to type `octave --no-gui`, it pop out the octave-cli window (Please refer to the image attached). 
[image]
Here are the questions:

1. How can I use octave-cli in the terminal of vscode?
2. Can I disable octave use gui when I type `octave` or I can only type `octave --no-gui` to use cli version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the octave.vbs file that most people use to start octave, there is also an octave.bat file located under `%OCTAVE-HOME%/mingw64/bin`.

I'm not familiar with vscode, but if I open a Windows command prompt, navigate to `c:\Octave\octave-6.4.0-w64\mingw64`, and type `octave.bat` (no options used), it opens octave in the existing window.

Comment: Problem fixed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Run Octave in VSCode Jupyter Notebook

You can change line `octave-cli.exe %` to `octave-gui.exe --no-gui %` in file `octave.bat`:

```
Rem   Start Octave (this detaches and immediately returns).

if %GUI_MODE%==1 (
  start octave-gui.exe --gui %*
) else (
  octave-gui.exe --no-gui %*
  Rem  octave-cli.exe %*
)
```

Instead of starting **octave-cli.exe** you are starting GUI `octave-gui.exe --no-gui` without graphical use interface.

Check available graphics toolkits in octave:

```
octave> available_graphics_toolkits()
```

Answer should be

```
ans = {
  [1,1] = fltk
  [1,2] = gnuplot  
  [1,3] = qt
}
```

Check which graphics toolkit is used

```
graphics_toolkit()
ans = qt
```

Answer should be **qt**.
Benefit of the change is that now you can use best inline graphics in **Jupyter Notebook**s and also in **VSCode Jupyter Notebook**s.

John